# Вечером себя порадовал БУРТУЧОМ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

как правильно? "Вечером себя порадовал буртучом" или "С буртучом"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Вечером порадовал себя (чем?) бртучом***.

Бртуч https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87

Answer (score 0):

*Долго думал, как это всё сформулировать и изложить, так и не сообразил. Но попробую...*

Слово в варианте буртуч словарями не фиксируется, вообще никакими.
Вариант бртуч оставляет вариативность формы брт**у**чем и бртуч**о**м. Я за  первый вариант, поскольку мотивов для смещения ударения в иноязычном слове нет.

Теперь собственно ответ. 
Грамматически допустимы варианты "порадовал бртучем" и "порадовал с бртучем" (порадовал с чем?), но первый из них вполне естественный, передает обычное  действие, тогда как второй требует какого-то очень необычного, чуть ли не фантастического  контекста (тира *"утром пил пиво натощак, а вечером порадовал себя [им же] с бртучем"* - да и то это на грани осмысленности).

Поэтому предлагаю как основной вариант ***"порадовал себя бртучем"***.
Но при всей уверенности в этом варианте, строго говоря, это только догадка.

(+)
Добавлю. Вот в чем остаются сомнения,  так в это в том, что речь идет именно об армянском кушанье **бртуч**.

Дело в том, что для передачи на русском армянского сверхкраткого звука (не фиксируемого в оригинале на письме, но "забирающегося" обычно в скопление согласных) обычно используется   звук Ы, много реже - Э. Фактически это и есть сверхкраткий гласный, не имеющий собственной фиксации в МФА, но близкий к [ə], нечто среднее между сверхкраткими Ы и Э, аналог которому можно найти в русских словах теат(ы)р, руб(ы)ль и т. п. при их "протяженном" произношении. Сравните, например, варианты передачи на русском фамилии Мкртычян (Мкртычан), Мкртчян (Мкртчан) и еще несколько вариантов вплоть до Мыкыртычан. Все они восходят к армянскому имени Мкртыч (в орфографическом эквиваленте, один гласный звук в армянском обычно фиксируется на письме в любом слове, даже если он сверхраткий).

Но крайне странно видеть там У.

Это длинное рассуждение, но оно всего лишь изложение причин сомнения в правильности интерпретации "буртуч" как "бртуч".